# unable to get test eth for Goerli testnet , and it is showing this error all the time"url doesn't link to supported services"

Tags: ether, metamask, wallets, testnets, goerli

I have tried to get it with both tweeter post and facebook post links to get eth,But they are not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This faucet is Alchemy's and it's super reliable - https://goerlifaucet.com/. You can get more daily if you need

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the Goerli testnet faucet goes down with demand and traffic - and it looks like there is a lot of demand for Goerli right now.

The MyCrypto Faucet should be still up - and feel free to shoot us an email if you need more than that.

Comment: I have connected my metamask wallet to mycrypto and tried to request some GOERLIETH and it generated some qr code and payment code. But could not find any option or button to submint the request. could you please guide me what can be done?

Comment: [It's broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BTw4j.png)...